VSCode not discovering pytests for Django Project
I am trying to use VSCode's testing sidebar with my Django Project, but it is unable to find the pytest files.
Here are the commands I've run to create this example project:
django-admin startproject LearningPytest
pip install django-pytest
Then I've created two files: pytest.ini and basic_tests.py, so my folder structure is as follows.
DjangoPyTesting/
└───LearningPytest/
    ├───LearningPytest/
    │   ├───__init__.py
    │   ├───asgi.py
    │   ├───basic_tests.py
    │   ├───settings.py
    │   ├───urls.py
    │   ├───wsgi.py
    ├───manage.py
    └───pytest.ini

pytest.ini
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = LearningPytest.settings
python_files = tests.py test_*.py *_tests.py
python_classes = Test*
python_functions = test_*

basic_tests.py
class TestBasicMath:
    
    def setup_method(self, method):
        self.x = 2
        self.y = 3
    
    def test_addition(self):
        assert self.x + self.y == 5 

    def test_subtraction(self):
        assert self.y - self.x == 1

    def test_multiplication(self):
        assert self.x * self.y == 6

Here is the problem, I want to use VSCode's sidebar to run my tests, but it cannot find them.

This confuses me, because within my project if I run the following command:
DjangoPytesting\LearningPytest>pytest
it works successfully
platform win32 -- Python 3.11.5, pytest-7.4.4, pluggy-1.3.0
rootdir: C:\Users\{me}\Desktop\DjangoPytesting\LearningPytest
configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: anyio-4.3.0, django-4.9.0
collected 3 items

LearningPytest\basic_tests.py ...platform win32 -- Python 3.11.5, pytest-7.4.4, pluggy-1.3.0
rootdir: C:\Users\{me}\Desktop\DjangoPytesting\LearningPytest
configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: anyio-4.3.0, django-4.9.0
collected 3 items

LearningPytest\basic_tests.py ... 3 passed in 0.02s

But if I attempt to run the pytest one level higher, it cannot find any tests, and I think this may be related to the problem.
DjangoPytesting>pytest
platform win32 -- Python 3.11.5, pytest-7.4.4, pluggy-1.3.0
rootdir: C:\Users\{me}\Desktop\DjangoPytesting
plugins: anyio-4.3.0, django-4.9.0
collected 0 items 
no tests ran in 0.01s

How can I get VSCode's sidebar to find my pytests, so I can run the testing there?
Unsuccessful attempted solutions:

using '> Developer: Reload Window'
https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html
renaming the file ('test.py', 'tests.py', 'LearningPytest_tests.py')


The Python extension also offers support for discovering and running Django unit tests starting from VSCode 1.93. You can get your Django tests discovered with only a few additional setup steps:

Set "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true, in your settings.json
file.
Add MANAGE_PY_PATH as an environment variable: Create a .env file
at the root of your project.
Add MANAGE_PY_PATH='<path-to-manage.py>' to the .env file,
replacing <path-to-manage.py> with the path to your application's
manage.py file.
Add Django test arguments to "python.testing.unittestArgs": [] in
the settings.json file as needed, and remove any arguments that are
not compatible with Django.

PS:If your .venv file is not located at your project root please add "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/<path-to-.env>" to your settings.json to ensure all your environmental variables get discovered.
